# GlobalStreamThread is using all JVM memory

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream topology where we use non-overlapping windows.

```
.groupBy((userId, brandId) -> brandId, Grouped.with(repartitionTopic, Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(ofMinutes(1)).advanceBy(ofMinutes(1)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
.aggregate(() -> 0L, (key, value, viewCount) -> viewCount + 1, storeBuilder())
.suppress(untilWindowCloses(unbounded())
.toStream()
```

`storeBuilder()` builds window store which is an unlogged in memory store implemented like this:

```
Materialized
    .as(inMemoryWindowStore(storeName, retentionPeriod, windowSize, false)
    .withCachingDisabled()
    .withLoggingDisabled()
    .withKeySerde(keySerde)
    .withValueSerde(valueSerde);
```

We don't use any kind of GlobalKTables. However, by looking at heap memory usage, I see there is `GlobalStreamThread` that is consuming 70% of the memory of JVM and from time to time it causes JVM to crash by allocating too much memory.

I would like to know, what this `GlobalStreamThread` is doing and is this the result of unlogged window store?

Comment: That is weird. The "global thread" should not even be created if you don't use global KTables or global state. What version are you using? Can you step into `KafkaStreams#start()` to see if/whey the global thread is started at all?